# Spray route inside IDEA complains about false error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, spray

I'm using spray and I have the following code:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.routing.Directives
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport.sprayJsonMarshaller
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport.sprayJsonUnmarshaller

case class SomeResult(id: String, color: String)

trait Protocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val someResultFormat = jsonFormat2(SomeResult)
}

trait Api extends Directives with Protocols {

  val route =
    path("order" / IntNumber) { id =>
      get {
        complete {
          val result: List[SomeResult] = List(SomeResult("foo", "green"+id), SomeResult("bar", "red"+id))
          result
        } // ERROR HERE
      }
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, however, inside IntelliJ IDEA editor it complains about an error. Namely, it says that *Expression of type List[SomeResult] doesn't conform to expected type ToResponseMarshallable*. How can I avoid the IDE complaining about such things? is there any fix for this? is it a well-known error? I already invalidated cache files and restarted but the error persist.

FWIW, I'm using:

Scala 2.11.1

Spray 1.3.1

IDEA  14.0.3

Scala plugin 1.3.2

JDK   1.7.0_71

Comment: My advice is not to rely on IntelliJ for the correctness of your code, but take it as only a heads up. If the official Scala compiler says that everything is fine, then you should go with that. I usually run a compilation process in the background (using sbt), which I double check when some error is raised within IntelliJ.

Comment: It's well-known that IDEA has various problems with its scala highlighting. They do improve it - keep updating the scala plugin as new versions are released - but the problems are many. Scala-IDE is more reliable in this respect (its highlighting is always accurate in my experience), but has its own issues.

Comment: You should ticket this in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A+Scala